# Changing urlpath with Object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I need to know how to replace the urltext with an object using javavscript.

If the url is `www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details?amount=1000&scy=SGD` and if the `lang` is `en`, then replace the url with matching object key and if the `lang` is `zh` then replace the url with the matching object value.

```
ExpectedOutput:
if url is 
www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin?amount=1000&scy=SGD 
=> output :www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin?amount=1000&scy=SGD

if url is 
www.xyz.com/zh/all-services-from-mal-to-sin?amount=1000&scy=SGD  
=> output: www.xyz.com/zh/hui-zhi-phi-tho-zmal-zhi-stin?amount=1000&scy=SG

if url is 
www.xyz.com/en/hui-zhi-phi-tho-zmal-zhi-stin?amount=1000&scy=SG 
 => output: www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin?amount=1000&scy=SGD
```

```
var obj1={
    "transfer-services": "xi-hou-zhi-n",
    "about-info": "zhi-zhu",
    "contact": "zhi-phi",
    "all-services-from": "hui-zhi-phi-tho",
    "to": "zhi",
    "sin": "stin",
    "mal": "zmal"
};

function transformURL(url,value) {
    let [base, lang, segment, ...rest] = url.split('/');
    lang=value;
    if(obj1.hasOwnProperty(segment)) {
        segment = obj1[segment];
    } else {
        Object.entries(obj1).forEach(([key, val]) => {
            if(val == segment) {segment = key};
        });
    }

    return [base, lang, segment, ...rest].join('/');
}
console.log(transformURL('www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin?amount=1000&scy=SGD', "zh"));
```

Comment: What should be your output url?

Comment: @RAVIPATEL  thanks for reply, mentioned in Expected Output

Comment: It's so specific, I would just use `if` conditionals or a `switch`. You're making this harder than it needs to be. `String.replace()`.

Comment: @StackSlave thanks for reply, apologies, updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping you have is en to zh, if you want 2 way conversion you need the reverse mapping too.

And your check `obj1.hasOwnProperty(segment)` and `val === segment` both of them are never going to work as all the keys in your object are partial, your segment is a combination of multiple keys, so you need to loop through the keys, check if key is part of the segment and replace that part of the segment.

```
const enToZh = {
    "transfer-services": "xi-hou-zhi-n",
    "about-info": "zhi-zhu",
    "contact": "zhi-phi",
    "all-services-from": "hui-zhi-phi-tho",
    "to": "zhi",
    "sin": "stin",
    "mal": "zmal"
};

const zhToEn = Object.keys(enToZh).reduce((a, c) => (
    { ...a, [enToZh[c]]: c }
), {});

function transformURL(url) {
    let [base, lang, segment, ...rest] = url.split('/');
    const obj = lang === 'en' ? zhToEn : enToZh;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        segment = segment.replace(key, obj[key]);
    });

    return [base, lang, segment, ...rest].join('/');
}

console.log(transformURL('www.xyz.com/zh/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details?amount=1000&scy=SGD'));
```

Comment: it works for two languages but doesnot work for multi language scenario, can you please please help, got stuck in code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57138754/multilanguage-urlpath-change-with-object-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
function transformURL(url,value) {
let [base, lang, segment, ...rest] = url.split('/');
lang=value;

var newsegment=segment.split('?')[0]

   if(lang=="zh")
   {
       newsegment = obj1["all-services-from"]+"-"+obj1["mal"]+"-"+obj1["to"]+"-"+obj1["sin"]+"?"+segment.split('?')[1];
   }else{
      newsegment = "all-services-from"+"-"+"mal"+"-"+"to"+"-"+"sin"+"?"+segment.split('?')[1];
   }

   return [base, lang, newsegment, ...rest].join('/');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d2tq4w3r/