# Multilanguage urlpath change with object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to change urlpath based on multiple languages.

If the url is www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details?amount=1000&scy=SGD and if the lang is `en`, then replace the url with matching object key and if the lang is `zh` then replace the url with the matching object value.

how to replace the urltext with an object using javavscript

```
// for en will receive obj as
{
    "transfer-services": "transfer-services",
    "about-info": "zhi-zhu",
    "contact": "zhi-phi",
    "all-services-from": "all-services-from",
    "to": "to",
    "sin": "sin",
    "mal": "zmal"
};
// for zh will receive obj as
{
    "transfer-services": "xi-hou-zhi-n",
    "about-info": "zhi-zhu",
    "contact": "zhi-phi",
    "all-services-from": "hui-zhi-phi-tho",
    "to": "zhi",
    "sin": "stin",
    "mal": "zmal"
};
// for hi will receive obj as
{
   "transfer-services": "sabhee sevaen",
    "about-info": "baare-mein",
    "contact": "sampark-karen",
    "all-services-from": "sabhee-sevak",
    "to": "se",
    "sin": "sg",
    "mal": "ml"
}

// will receive above obj base on curr_lang and prev_lang
function translationUrl(langvalue) {
  var result = $.ajax({
    url: "/" + langvalue,
    method: "get",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      urllang: langvalue
    },
    success: function (data) {
     return data;
    }
  }).responseText;
  return JSON.parse(result).language.urltext;
}

 var prevObj = translationUrl(prev_lang);
 var currentObj = translationUrl(curr_lang);

 function swapObj(val) {
      const lang = Object.keys(val).reduce((a, c) => (
        { ...a, [val[c]]: c }
      ), {});
      return lang;
    }

    function transformURL(url, curr_lang, prev_lang, prevObj , currObj) { // convert prev to curr lang
        let [base, lang, segment, ...rest] = url.split('/');
        const obj = lang === prev_lang ? currObj: swapObj(currObj);
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            segment = segment.replace(key, obj[key]);
        });

        return [base, lang, segment, ...rest].join('/');
    }

    console.log(transformURL('www.xyz.com/zh/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details?amount=1000&scy=SGD'),"zh", "hi",prevObj , currObj );
```

Expected outputs:

```
var prev_lang ="en";
var curr_lang = "hi";
if url is 
www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin?amount=1000&scy=SGD 
=> output :www.xyz.com/hi/sabhee-sevak-ml-to-sg?amount=1000&scy=SGD

var prev_lang ="hi";
var curr_lang = "zh";
if url is 
www.xyz.com/hi/sabhee-sevak-ml-to-sg?amount=1000&scy=SGD
=> output :www.xyz.com/zh/hui-zhi-phi-tho-zmal-zhi-stin?amount=1000&scy=SG

var prev_lang ="hi";
var curr_lang = "en";
if url is 
www.xyz.com/hi/sabhee-sevak-ml-to-sg?amount=1000&scy=SGD
=> output :www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin?amount=1000&scy=SGD
```

Comment: What is your current output? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @JonathanLam thanks for reply, it works when the url is  `www.xyz.com/zh/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details?amount=1000&scy=SGD to www.xyz.com/hi/sabhee-sevak-ml-to-sg?amount=1000&scy=SGD` but not work for curr_lang = en and prev_lang =zh ,

Comment: What does `swapObj()` do? And why is `obj` hardcoded to be either `hi` or `swapObj(hi)`? Could this be the cause of your problem?

Comment: @JonathanLam have updated my code, can you please check, `swapObj` will reverse the map like { "transfer-services": "sabhee sevaen" } to  {  "sabhee sevaen" :"transfer-services"}  and vive-versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to cast two objects into one such that values of one becomes key and value of another value as your base object is `en` for case 2. Also I've change `se` to `seh` in `hi` object as it was clashing with `services`. Consider the following (first is the actual output, second is the desired output):

```js
// for en will receive obj as

let en = {
  "transfer-services": "transfer-services",
  "about-info": "zhi-zhu",
  "contact": "zhi-phi",
  "all-services-from": "all-services-from",
  "to": "to",
  "sin": "sin",
  "mal": "zmal"
};
// for zh will receive obj as
let zh = {
  "transfer-services": "xi-hou-zhi-n",
  "about-info": "zhi-zhu",
  "contact": "zhi-phi",
  "all-services-from": "hui-zhi-phi-tho",
  "to": "zhi",
  "sin": "stin",
  "mal": "zmal"
};
// for hi will receive obj as
let hi = {
  "transfer-services": "sabhee sevaen",
  "about-info": "baare-mein",
  "contact": "sampark-karen",
  "all-services-from": "sabhee-sevak",
  "to": "seh",
  "sin": "sg",
  "mal": "ml"
};

// will receive above obj base on curr_lang and prev_lang
function translationUrl(langvalue) {
  switch (langvalue) {
    case 'hi':
      return hi;
    case 'zh':
      return zh;
    case 'en':
      return en;
  }
}

function swapObj(val) {
  const lang = Object.keys(val).reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a,
    [val[c]]: c
  }), {});
  return lang;
}

function castObj(prev, curr) {
  const lang = Object.keys(currObj).reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a,
    [currObj[c]]: prevObj[c]
  }), {});
  return lang;
}

function transformURL(url, curr_lang, prev_lang, prevObj, currObj) { // convert prev to curr lang
  let [base, lang, segment, ...rest] = url.split('/');
  let obj = lang === prev_lang ? currObj : swapObj(currObj);

  if (prev_lang !== 'en' && curr_lang !== 'en')
    obj = swapObj(castObj(prevObj, currObj));
  if (prev_lang !== 'en' && curr_lang === 'en')
    obj = swapObj(prevObj);

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    segment = segment.replace(key, obj[key]);
  });

  return [base, curr_lang, segment, ...rest].join('/');
}


let prev_lang = "en";
let curr_lang = "hi";

var prevObj = translationUrl(prev_lang);
var currObj = translationUrl(curr_lang);

console.log(transformURL('www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin?amount=1000&scy=SGD', curr_lang, prev_lang, prevObj, currObj));
console.log('www.xyz.com/hi/sabhee-sevak-ml-seh-sg?amount=1000&scy=SGD');

prev_lang = "hi";
curr_lang = "zh";
prevObj = translationUrl(prev_lang);
currObj = translationUrl(curr_lang);

console.log(transformURL('www.xyz.com/hi/sabhee-sevak-ml-seh-sg?amount=1000&scy=SGD', curr_lang, prev_lang, prevObj, currObj));
console.log('www.xyz.com/zh/hui-zhi-phi-tho-zmal-zhi-stin?amount=1000&scy=SGD');

prev_lang = "hi";
curr_lang = "en";
prevObj = translationUrl(prev_lang);
currObj = translationUrl(curr_lang);

console.log(transformURL('www.xyz.com/hi/sabhee-sevak-ml-seh-sg?amount=1000&scy=SGD', curr_lang, prev_lang, prevObj, currObj));
console.log('www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin?amount=1000&scy=SGD');
```

Comment: thanks for help, for example if zh has two more obj {"estontia": "ai-sha-ni-ya", "to": "zhi"} , when i try `www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-estonia-to-sin?amount=1000&scy=SGD` it shows, `www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-eszhinia-to-stin?amount=1000&scy=SGD` , object replaces wrongly, in`estonia` to` replaces `zhi`, can you help

Comment: @Senthil what is the input and desired url

Comment: thanks for reply, have added the code in your solution last.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue in this manner.
simply return the new prev_lang.

You were not passing the element to function properly, while console.log
It needs to pass in this manner:

```
   console.log(transformURL('www.xyz.com/zh/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details?amount=1000&scy=SGD',"zh", "hi",prevObj , currentObj) );
```

The second problem was you were returning the same lang of actual URL which needs to be changed. No need of swapObj()

```js
// for en will receive obj as
var en = {
 "transfer-services": "transfer-services",
 "about-info": "about-info",
 "contact": "contact",
 "all-services-from": "all-services-from",
 "to": "to",
 "sin": "sin",
 "mal": "zmal"
};
// for zh will receive obj as
var zh = {
 "transfer-services": "xi-hou-zhi-n",
 "about-info": "zhi-zhu",
 "contact": "zhi-phi",
 "all-services-from": "hui-zhi-phi-tho",
 "to": "zhi",
 "sin": "stin",
 "mal": "zmal"
};
// for hi will receive obj as
var hi = {
 "transfer-services": "sabhee sevaen",
 "about-info": "baare-mein",
 "contact": "sampark-karen",
 "all-services-from": "sabhee-sevak",
 "to": "se",
 "sin": "sg",
 "mal": "ml"
}


var prevObj = hi;
var currentObj = en;


Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function (value) {
 for (var prop in this) {
  if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
   if (this[prop] === value)
    return prop;
  }
 }
}

function searchReplace(segment, obj){
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  segment = segment.replace(obj[key], obj.getKeyByValue(obj[key]));
 });
  segment = segment.replace("torvices","services");
  return segment;

}

function transformURL(url, curr_lang, prev_lang, prevObj, currObj) { // convert prev to curr lang
 let [base, lang, segment, ...rest] = url.split('/');
 lang = curr_lang
 var obj = currObj;
  segment = searchReplace(segment, obj);

 var obj = prevObj;
  segment = searchReplace(segment, obj);


 return [base, prev_lang, segment, ...rest].join('/');
}

console.log(transformURL('www.xyz.com/hi/sabhee-sevak-ml-se-sg/details?amount=1000&scy=SGD', "hi", "en", prevObj, currentObj));
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but if you `var prevObj = hi;
     var currentObj = en;`, transformURL('www.xyz.com/hi/sabhee-sevak-ml-se-sg/details?amount=1000&scy=SGD',"hi", "en",prevObj , currentObj); not working?

Comment: hello @Senthil i have done this for sample test. var prevObj = hi; var currentObj = en; Please try to run snippet above

Comment: have tried and inserted the code, can you please check, `urltext doesnot modify only lang code`, for that purpose i used swapobj which reverses the obj `like { "transfer-services": "sabhee sevaen" } to { "sabhee sevaen" :"transfer-services"} and vice-versa`

Comment: Okay i got your problem,  the main issue is with your object which you are creating is not having keys for all language translation

Comment: yes that why i used `swapobj` but got stuck in between code

Comment: with all combinations of langcode url should change the text , if possible help please

Comment: Swapping will not help you out, either you should use the fixed keys which will generate the segment based on langauge

Comment: fix keys for each language its bit hard, have more 10 languages,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196793/discussion-between-rishab-and-senthil).